# Messaging.SingleEmailMessage translated labels

Tags: apex, batch, singleemailmessage, translation-workbench

I have a batch that sends an article through email to contacts.

I have a field in the Article Object which indicates the lang of the article.

I'm using Messaging.SingleEmailMessage and I have picklists values that I translated in Translation Workbench, and I wondering how can I send the data of the picklists and the fields label base on the lang field that I have in the Article Object.

Is there a variable in Messaging.SingleEmailMessage which decide the lang?

I didn't find anything about it.

I defined the lang in Translation Workbench respectively to the lang field.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use `toLabel(picklist)`?

Comment: toLabel is translated into the language for the user who issued the query.
The batch is running by an application user.
I need the lang to be determined by a lang field on the object who have the picklists inside him..

Comment: I am also stuck on the same issue? did you get some solution on this?

Comment: Hi @KamranJabbar, unfortunately, I didn't find a solution for this, we don't send the value of the picklist eventually because of this, we just sorting the records before sending them base on the value of the picklists without putting them inside the email, but this something we decide to do together with the client... so It's not a solution or a workaround. sorry.